# French language while installing office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office

I am using iso file to install MS Office 2013 but the setup runs in french. Is there anyway to run setup in english language?

Comment: Are you using a .msi installer or Click-to-run installer ?

Comment: I have a disc image for office 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm sorry it isn't possible to change the setup program's language.

In fact, you won't be even able to change the whole Office language to English once it's installed, unless you buy a Language Interface Pack (LIP).

> From the [**Office support page**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Language-Interface-Pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1):
>
> Language interface packs (LIPs) are free downloads and are only available for the languages listed in the Languages available as free LIP downloads section.
>
> If you are looking for languages like English, French, Japanese, Russian, and Turkish, **you need to buy a language pack**.

I've dealt with this problem before, and the only solution is to find the proper .ISO for your language.